# Acentuação da palavra coroa

Tags: acentos-ou-sotaques

Olá estou com uma duvida em relação a palavra coroa/corôa, especificamente no sentido de ornamento em forma circular usado por reis, ela leva acento? é um caso de dupla grafia/prosódia?

A confusão piora por causa dos diferentes significados da palavra coroa, como mulher velha, governo, moeda, verbo ect. Logo não sei se o acento é usado pra diferenciar ou se é uma diferença regional, sou do Brasil.

Comment: Estou surpreso, nunca vi "coroa" escrito com acento. Agora fiquei curioso pra saber onde é escrito dessa forma...

Comment: Lui, podes consultar a grafia de qualquer palavra num dicionário online, como o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cor%C3%B4a) ou [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=cor%C3%B4a) (pronto, agora incluí mesmo os links). @Hugo, eu só vi *corôa*, e apenas esporadicamente, na grafia do sXIX, quando se escrevia *pharmacia* e *hypothese*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A palavra *coroa* pode assumir dois significados:

- Como substantivo, representa o acessório usado por certas figuras de autoridade, como reis. Alternativamente, também pode ser uma gíria para pessoas de idade mais avançada. A pronúncia, nesta forma, é fechada (/*ô*/).
- Como verbo, representa a flexão do verbo *coroar* (que significa "condecorar", "reconhecer") na terceira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo (*ele/ela coroa*). A pronúncia, nesta forma, é aberta (/*ó*/).

Para distinguir ambas as formas na língua escrita, costumava-se usar o acento circunflexo no substantivo. Mas, com a assinatura da [Reforma Ortográfica de 1971](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforma_Ortogr%C3%A1fica_de_1971), a maioria dos acentos diferenciais foi eliminada da língua:

> Em Portugal, entre 1911 e 1945, assim como no Brasil entre 1943 e 1971, houve a existência de um recurso chamado acento diferencial. Dada a existência de muitas palavras homógrafas mas não homófonas, julgou-se necessário criar diferenciações entre elas:
>
> - pilôto (substantivo) / piloto (ó) (do verbo "pilotar");
> - côr (vermelho, amarelo, etc) / Cor (ó) (coração);
> - êle (pronome) / ele (é) (nome dado à letra L);
> - govêrno (substantivo) / governo (é) (verbo);

Hoje em dia, a forma *corôa* é considerada gramaticalmente incorreta e desnecessária, mas ainda pode ser usada em citações de obras anteriores ao vigor da Reforma.

Comment: Tens a certeza que se escrevia *corôa* no Brasil antes de 1971? Eu encontro *coroa*, mas não *corôa*. Só encontro *corôa* em textos do sXIX e anteriores às reformas de 1911 e 1943. Em Portugal o substantivo e a forma do verbo são homónimas.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, algumas construções antigas ainda possuem letreiros com o acento. Mas, agora que me perguntas, não sei dizer o quão antigas estas construções são. E, se não estou enganado, a Reforma de 1971 é a versão brasileira da Reforma de 1943, com certas diferenças regionais, logicamente.

Comment: Sim, os acentos diferenciais dos antigos *emprêgo, acôrdo*, etc. foram abolidos em Portugal em 1945 e no Brasil em 1971. Mas *coroa*, em Portugal, não estava nessa classe de palavras. Só se encontra *corôa* esporadicamente na grafia anterior a 1911 de Portugal/1943 do Brasil.

Comment: Quando dizes que a pronúncia de "ele **coroa** o rei" é aberta (*/ó/*), isso é no Brasil? Aqui em Portugal, eu diria esse o fechado (*/ô/*).

Comment: Evidentemente o acento de "corôa", "pessôa", etc, nunca foi um acento diferencial; não existe na língua nenhuma palavra pronunciada "coróa". É outro acento, com outra finalidade.

Comment: Não é comum alguém falar 'ele coróa o rei' em pt-BR, talvez em alguns Estados do nordeste brasileiro.

Answer (score 0):

Coroa termina em A e é grave, como é expectavel, portanto não carece de acento para indicar a vogal tonica.

A ter acento, seria um acento diferencial, o que não é o caso.